# SQL Developer Trigger for theatre database

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I am new to SQL and I am trying to create a trigger for my theatre database project for school.
A theatre has a number of seats. For example the Apollo Theater has got 2100 seats. A show is visited by guests. I'd like to create a trigger, which checks whether the number of guests is greater than the number of seats and corrects it. The following code is only for the Apollo Theatre, I've got 2 more theatres in the database. If the code works I will add them on my own :)

```
create or replace trigger seats
before insert on show
for each row
when (old.number_of_guests is not null)
declare name_theatre show.name_theatre%TYPE;
begin
    if name_theatre = 'Apollo Theatre' and :new.guests > 2100
    then :new.number_of_guests := 2100;
    end if;
end;
```

The code compiles, but if I insert a show with 2200 guests the trigger doesn't change it to 2100.
Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: An `insert` has no `old` record.

Comment: ok but it doesn't compile without "old`" and it doesn't work with "new". so unfortunately it didn't fix my problem

Comment: I understand this is a class assignment and you have to do what was assigned, but allow me to point out 3 "real world" problems.  First, this is actually a very poor case for a trigger. This should be taken care of in the application code. Google 'the trouble with triggers". Second, don't hard-code the theaters capacity. This should be selected from a 'theaters' table. Third don't store number of seats sold. Compute it when needed by selecting from a 'tickets' or 'guests' table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `old` in insert trigger and all values must use `:new`. And you are declaring variable which is not assigned any value. That variable is not at all requited.

```
create or replace trigger seats
before insert on show
for each row
begin
    if :new.name_theatre = 'Apollo Theatre' and :new.guests > 2100
    then :new.number_of_guests := 2100;
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You must accept the answer if it worked for you so that this question is marked as resolved.

Comment: @Tejash - *"You must accept the answer "* Actually there is no compulsion for a Seeker to accept an answer, however helpful, although we definitely encourage them to do so.

Comment: Ok @APC. I understand. But this is to clear the question from the open list.